# Rails display related posts by tags with images from carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, carrierwave, acts-as-taggable-on

postI'm trying to retrieve related posts by tags by showing the **attached image** per related post, uploaded by using the carrierwave gem

Tags were written from scratch but similar to **acts-as-taggable-on gem**. 
Below solution picked from [Rails count article per tag and related article by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588594/rails-count-article-per-tag-and-related-article-by-tag) displays the related posts by title.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<% post.tags.each do |tag| %>

RELATED POSTS:
<% tag.posts.each do |related_post| %>
<%= link_to related_post.title + " , ", post %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want related posts to be displayed by image instead of `title` per above. Code displaying image for post is

```
<%= image_tag(post.cover.url(:thumb)) if post.cover? %>
```

**How can I fit this in the RELATED POSTS above?**
I tried

```
<%= image_tag(related_post.cover.url(:thumb)) if post.cover? %>
```

but this throws:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'related_post' for #<#:0x007fb67db38fb8>

Obviously `related_post` is not recorded in the carrierwave uploader model since it is different from the tags model. Any help please?

Comment: whats your model relation ? has_many to belongs ?

Comment: Try this one if yr not getting error, let me know. `<%= image_tag(related_post.first.cover.url(:thumb)) if song.cover? %>`

Comment: Thanks @7urkm3n - I have tried it but still showing error: undefined method `first' for. Model relation is Post 'has_many :taggings' 'has_many :tags, through: :taggings' . Tag 'has_many :taggings' 'has_many :posts, through: :taggings' . Tagging 'belongs_to :post'
  belongs_to :tag

Comment: can u post your DB relations.

Comment: app/models/post.rb

has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings

app/models/tag.rb

has_many :taggings
has_many :posts, through: :taggings

app/models/tagging.rb 

belongs_to :post
belongs_to :tag

Comment: so where is your `cover.url` located, in `posts` table ?

Comment: is `carrierwave` uploads an image? did you check it in `rails console` ?

Comment: Yes carrierwave is being able to upload the images which shows in the console as cover: "image.jpg". Image for post is also showing on index page by using <%= image_tag(post.cover.url(:thumb)) if post.cover? %> However I want to show related post by image, so I thought **related_post.cover.url** would work since related_post.title.url is able to display related posts by **titles** hope this makes sense

Comment: can you provide more codes? also if this one works `<%= link_to related_post.title + " , ", post %>` then `<%= link_to related_post.cover.url, post %>` should work too, if you have `cover` column in posts table.

Comment: This worked:  `<%= image_tag(related_post.cover.url(:thumb) %>` Thanks a lot!

Comment: i see nothing difference there, from your previous one

Comment: Correct, but I might have done something wrong in the previous which was throwing an error